# Quarter end from today's date

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get a quarter end date based on today's date, but I wanted to strip the time first. If I do that, the below code throws me an error on the last line **AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'to_period'**

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

today_datetime = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
today_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(today_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')
df['Qend'] = today_date.to_period("Q").end_time
```

Could you advise me, how to improve it to get the Quarter end of today's date without time, please?

Comment: pd.Timestamp.now().to_period('Q').end_time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering @Ezer-k comment, below is code, which insert quarter end date based on current date with stripped time.

```
today_datetime = pd.Timestamp.now()
# get month end stripped time
df['Qend'] = today_datetime.to_period('M').end_time
df['Qend'] = df['Qend'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

I'm sure there might be better way also, but just to return with correct answer.